# Adding Snapkit to xcode manually

Tags: swift, xcode, snapkit

How to add **Snapkit** in *xcode* manually without using **cocoapods** or **carthage** ?

Comment: What are your reasoning for deciding against using cocoapods or Carthage for dependency management? Just curious, as cocoa pods and Carthage makes it easier to update, maintain your dependencies, and you can even set a dependency to a fixed version, as I think might be the reasoning for you? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download project from [repo](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) or you can download only [source](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/tree/develop/Source) file.

Then drag and drop that source file into your project.

And you are good to go.

Check example code which is given into their repo.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var box = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(box)
        box.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.width.height.equalTo(50)
            make.center.equalTo(self.view)
        }
    }
}
```

And its running without and errors:

[image]

**Note:** You don't need to `import SnapKit` if you are adding it manually.

Check complete project [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=52595350534081441165).